# Galaxy S - Calendar Add Event Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create simple editor screen - similar to the "Add Event" screen on Samsung Galaxy S Calendar App. That screen looks totally like a PreferenceScreen, with each item (event name, event date etc.) in a separate row. But I'm pretty sure that all the data from that screen are not saved as a SharedPreferences.

So my question is: do you have any idea how to create screen that will look similar? Should I define ListView with custom view for each row in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A listview is usually for a dynamic number of views. Sounds like you could easily do this with just a linearlayout or a scrollview.

Comment: I've found screenshot of this screen:
http://kollerie.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/samsung-galaxy-s-peculiarities-01/ (http://kollerie.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/02_create_event.png).
As you can see each item is separated with a line. I think it's not possible with LinearLayout. Each item behavior is similar to items in the ListView.

Comment: After some reasearch I came to a conclusion that it is PreferenceScreen with some custom Preferences. Screen is called with startActivityForResult and result of user input can be read from the Bundle.